# Need help in dynamic procedure

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a start date and end date so how to use both in place of getdate()

I have a code in which if the date interval between start and end date is less than 30 than it should show the start and end date. Instead it is showing error-

```
Explicit conversion from data type int to date is not allowed.
```

I am notusing int anywhere but still it is showing I have tried convert in argument passing and other things but its not stopping showing error.

My code is-

```
if object_id('ias_test_SCHEMA.week2','p') is not null
drop procedure ias_test_SCHEMA.week2;
go
create procedure ias_test_SCHEMA.week2(@startdate date,@enddate date) 
as
BEGIN
declare @datediff integer,
        @res varchar(30);

set @datediff = DATEDIFF(day, @startdate, @enddate);

if @datediff<=30 
begin
declare @stmt nvarchar(max),
        @stmt1 nvarchar(max);
set @stmt= N'SELECT @res=(DATENAME(DAY,convert(date,'+convert(nvarchar(20),@startdate)+'))  + '' '' + DATENAME(MONTH,convert(date,'+convert(nvarchar(20),@startdate)+')) + '' '' + DATENAME(YEAR,convert(date,'+convert(nvarchar(20),@startdate)+')))';
Execute sp_executesql @stmt, N'@res varchar output',
                             @res=@res output;
print 'The date is:' + @res;
set @stmt1= N'SELECT DATENAME(DAY,convert(date,'+convert(nvarchar(20),@enddate)+')) + '' '' + DATENAME(MONTH,convert(date,'+convert(nvarchar(20),@enddate)+')) + '' '' + DATENAME(YEAR,convert(date,'+convert(nvarchar(20),@enddate)+'))';
Execute sp_executesql @stmt1;
end;
end;
 go
```

and I am executing it by line-

```
execute ias_test_SCHEMA.week2 '2015-10-03','2015-10-08';
```

but it is showing compiled successfully but at the time of result is not showing error. I am stuck here!
Please can anyone help me through it? Thank you!

Comment: please PRINT you dynamic SQL and post here, which would be more helpful for viewers

Comment: I have posted my code there what do you want other than that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

these are the commands produced by your code:

```
SELECT @res=(DATENAME(DAY,convert(date,2015-10-03))  + ' ' + DATENAME(MONTH,convert(date,2015-10-03)) + ' ' + DATENAME(YEAR,convert(date,2015-10-03)))
SELECT DATENAME(DAY,convert(date,2015-10-08)) + ' ' + DATENAME(MONTH,convert(date,2015-10-08)) + ' ' + DATENAME(YEAR,convert(date,2015-10-08))
```

the issue is in the missing quotes around the dates inside the convert built in the dynamic string.

if you run:

```
select convert(date,2015-10-03);
```

you get:

> Msg 529, Level 16, State 2, Line 1 Explicit conversion from data type
>   int to date is not allowed.

the following command can be executed successfully:

```
select convert(date,'2015-10-03');
```

the solution is to add escaped single quotes when building the dynamic query:

```
set @stmt= N'SELECT @res=(DATENAME(DAY,convert(date,'''+convert(nvarchar(20),@startdate)+'''))  + '' '' + DATENAME(MONTH,convert(date,'''+convert(nvarchar(20),@startdate)+''')) + '' '' + DATENAME(YEAR,convert(date,'''+convert(nvarchar(20),@startdate)+''')))';
```

Comment: so I have to do something like this   SELECT @res=(DATENAME(DAY,convert(date,'2015-10-03')) or what do I change in code or in the execution statement?

Comment: please see my edit: you have to add escaped single quotes around the dates you combine to build the final query

Comment: but why in message it is always showing 3 instead of any value in dates